# Angular 11, HMR, wrong schema set, when used behind a asp.net core app with UseSpa

Tags: asp.net-core, angular-cli

I have an asp.net core app that uses:

```
app.UseSpa(x =>
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    x.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                    x.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                }
                else
                {
                    // x.Options.SourcePath
                    x.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
                    {
                        OnPrepareResponse = context =>
                        {
                            context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
                            context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "-1");
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
```

angular is started with:
`ng serve` which then serves the site on `http://localhost:4200`

The `--public-host` does not seem to respect the schema.

The docs says: `The URL that the browser client (or live-reload client, if enabled) should use to connect to the development server. Use for a complex dev server setup, such as one with reverse proxies.`

My API is hosted in the asp.net core app.

The browser tries to connect to: `https://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info?t=1605229799939` ... which is not running. Notice the https, which is gets from the asp.net core app which is being served over https.

I can get it to work if I start the angular dev server with --ssl, trust the certicate in my certificate store in Windows, so .NET trusts that certificate. The issues is that there is no override for the `UseSpa` as I have found, to trust self signed certificates, when running in development.

I want the setup to be as clean as possible, with the least amount of hacks, like trusting self signed certs on local machine.

Is there any way to let the HMR/nodejs/angular-cli know what it needs to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

Well ... setting `--public-host` to `localhost:5000` solved the issue.

Then it's just going though the asp.net core app which acts as a proxy. Not sure why I didn't think of that before creating this issue.

Comment: This was helpful to me :-) I'm curious why I didn't ever need to use this before. My guess is that HMR is now using https to connect (probably based on the scheme of your ASP.NET site) and perhaps before it wasn't, therefore https://localhost:4200/sock-js... can't reach your angular server unless it's running with ssl.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Exactly ... but happy my "mistake" could help other :-)

Comment: I sometimes test with a reverse proxy (Argo tunnel on cloudflare) and this allows me to not have the site suddenly refresh by putting public-host to `mytestwebsite.example.com`